# How to set Ids for forms with same name in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two HTML forms, both share same name. How to set ID to each form.

Set Form1 with Id ="updateSchedulerForm"

Set Form2 with Id ="createSchedulerForm"

Form 1

```
<form name="schedulerForm>
<input type="text" name="scheduletime"/>
</form>
```

Form 2

```
<form name="schedulerForm>
<input type="text" name="scheduletime"/>
</form>
```

How to set ID for each form in Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do use .attr() like

```
var $forms = $('form[name="schedulerForm"]');
$forms.eq(0).attr('id', 'updateSchedulerForm');
$forms.eq(1).attr('id', 'createSchedulerForm');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q7rbqhx0/)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Waiting for 3 mins to accept the answer.